# accessing index within a laravel collection

Tags: laravel

I'm new to Laravel and am trying to access an item inside of a collection:

```
$results = 
        [
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'Learning Laravel',
        ];

@php ($collection = collect($results))
@php ($value = $collection->get('name'))
```

returns nothing

when I use the example from the documentation:

```
@php ($collection = collect(['name' => 'taylor', 'framework' => 'laravel']))
@php ($value = $collection->get('name'))
```

this returns 'taylor'

Comment: instead of `collect([$results])` make it `collect($results)`

Comment: @Ersoy still getting nothing

Comment: can you post an output of `dd($collection)`?

Comment: make sure when you define your `$results` that it is within the @php directive

Comment: @ITDesigns.eu ($collection) returns [{"id":1,"name":"Learning Laravel"}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$collection->first()->name`.  Typically `get()` is used to return a collection from a pull.

Or, when you have an actual collection of multiple objects, you can select it by `$obj = $collection->where('name', 'Learning Laravel')->first();`  From here, you can manipulate the `$obj` object as you wish.

Like all things Laravel, there are many ways to do the same thing.  There's even a method called firstWhere.  So you could do: `$obj = $collection->firstWhere('id', 1);` for example.